# Access cookies of Iframe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

My websites are hosted on two domains :

1. foo.mydomain.com
2. bar.mydomain.com

In foo.mydomain.com, I'd like to open an iframe with src="bar.mydomain.com" and then access it's cookies. Is it possible?

The end goal is to retrieve a JSESSIONID cookie after a successful sign in in my iframe.

For now, I've tried

```
iframe.onload = () => {
      var signInForm = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("signInForm");
      console.log(signInForm)
    };
```

But I encountered **SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object** with Firefox.

Comment: Years ago you used to be able to set `document.domain` in the iframe page if it is always to be opened within the frame. You can also use [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API

Comment: Thank you! I'll dig into postMessage() then